# Linq2Entity Getting Values from reference Table

Tags: linq, reference, entity

i have 3 tables

Table: A
 - aID
 - Text

Table: B
 - bID
 - Text

Table: A_B (reference table which holds both of the primary keys as foreign keys)
 - aID
 - bID

The Entity Framework knows that Table A_B is just a reference table and does not create it in the DBModel but keeps the references in Table A and B.

My question is how do i get the data which is in the reference table without actually having this table? When i try to access the values of Table B using the reference which is in Table A i cant get the values of the Table B Colums.

```
        ObjectQuery<A> aTable = dbConnection.A;

        var result = from data in aTable
        where data.aID = '12'
        select data.B; //B is the reference to table B out of table A
```

What i need is something like:

```
        ObjectQuery<A> aTable = dbConnection.A;

        var result = from data in aTable
        where data.aID = '12'
        select data.B.bID;
```

How do i get data out of Table B using the reference between Table A and Table B?

Using: VS 2010 Prof, .Net 4, Linq2Entity

Comment: Can't you just manually join the tables?

Comment: This sounds like a many to many. Yet you are trying to access the `bId` as if it were a many-to-one relationship. A's reference to B will be a collection (as will be B's to A). If you are only expecting one B for A.aId = '12' you can use `select data.B.First().bId`. Otherwise you may want to look into `SelectMany`.

Answer (score 0):

As Gary Said, you either use First (if you want one B for each A), FirstOrDefault (if you want nulls where there is no B for A) or SelectMany (if you want all Bs for each A)
The latter can be written like this:

```
 var result = from data in dbConnection.A
              from b in data.B
              select b.Id;
```

Comment: Hey Guys, thx for your ideas! what i wanted works with tec-goblins idea!

Comment: Do you have any idea on my latest problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9173613/linq-adding-new-rows-to-table-when-there-is-a-relation-table

Comment: here is a solution to my latest problem
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/da2f4d7a-ef1e-48de-ac80-3d5d8a2a344d